# Why does using layout_below mess up the size of the start button?

Tags: android, xml

I have the following xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    tools:context=".StoppedActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalTimeView"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/started_black"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countDownView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/totalTimeView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
    android:textColor="@color/started_black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="65sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleSwitch"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/countDownView"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently it displays everything correctly on Nexus 5X, but the layout gets messed up when used in a device with a different screen size. To ensure that doesn't happen, I added the line

```
android:layout_below="@id/toggleSwitch"
```

to

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/toggleSwitch"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />
```

However, this messes up the sizing of the start button, why is this happening? How do I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you tell your layout that the button is going to fill the space available in between the bottom of`"@id/toggleSwitch` (that's what below does) and the bottom of your parent layout (because you specified `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`)

Instead, you can define a blank view filling the space between your toggle switch and your button, so it won't mess up you button height:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleSwitch"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/countDownView"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toggleSwitch"
    android:layout_above="@+id/startButton"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@id/startButton"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may have to adjust the code. But if you want to fill a vertical blank space with the available vertical space (Which I understand you're trying to do to adapt you layout for different phones), that's one way to do it. Alternatively, you could use a LinearLayout for the bottom of your screen and use the `layout_weight` attribute, but the above solution is probably cleaner if you want to keep your current layout implementation.